# Overlay for RelativeLayout inside ListView with match_parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am dealing with a weird problem.

I am using the following layout for `ListView` rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:jn="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.appeaser.justnoteproject"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <BUNCH OF VIEWS />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlCon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_note_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_note_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_note_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_note_bottom" >

    <BUNCH OF VIEWS />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_overlay"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my list adapter, I toggle `vOverlay's` visibility based on a certain condition. But, even after toggling the visibility, `vOverlay` is not displayed.

To verify that the code works as intended, I changed the height and width of `vOverlay` to `50dp`. When I did this, `vOverlay's` visibility worked as intended - except that the size I need is `match_parent`.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? How can I get intended results?

Comment: if you give size as match parent.then it will cover whole screen..just change it to wrap_content

Comment: @MeenalSharma I tried `wrap_content` just now. Still, `vOverlay` is not visible.

Comment: replace outer RelativeLayout with FrameLayout and move your overlay to be a second child of that FrameLayout

Comment: @pskink Tried that as well while keeping the height and width as `match_parent`. Still, `vOverlay` is no show.

Comment: @Mrinali see my modified comment above

Comment: @pskink Wow.. just wow. Please post an answer for me to mark. It would be great if you can spare a few minutes to explain the issue with using RelativeLayout.

Comment: honestly it should work with your code,  I don't know why it doesn't, Frame Layout is just a save way to get what you wanted

Comment: @pskink Ok. Fair enough. I'll keep this trick in mind. I will be leaving for work soon. So, it might take me some time to accept your answer (which I hope you do post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace outer RelativeLayout with FrameLayout and move your overlay to be a second child of that FrameLayout